# Non-simple circuit

Tags: graph-theory

I am sorry to ask such a straight-forward question, but I just cannot find a non-simple circuit with 5 edges in this graph. For us, a circuit is a closed path that does not repeat edges. A non-simple one will repeat a vertex different from the first one. If I am not mistaken, this is not possible here, as you need at least other 3 edges to return to a vertex and the first and last will thus be the same (joining this vertex and the first one), making it not a circuit.

[image]

Comment: $b-d-b-c-d-b$ seems to work for me.

Comment: @SlipEternal you seem to misunderstand.

Comment: i can take a triangle like f,e,h but then I must repeat a vertex and go back to f

Comment: @user376343 a non-simple circuit is one that repeats edges and/ or vertices. Another one could be $b-c-d-c-d-b$. It starts and ends on the same vertex, but since it repeats, it is non-simple.

Comment: a circuit does not repeat edges by definition...

Comment: @SlipEternal  a circuit does not repeat edges. Look also to the text in the question.

Comment: a circuit in general does not repeat edges. A non-simple circuit will repeat vertices.

Comment: Fair enough. My mistake. I misrembered the definition.

Comment: Pedro you´re right, such a circuit does not exist. The parity of vertices could not be fulfilled.

Comment: @pedro Does your book admit that a circuit can have length 2?  For example, in the given graph would $d-e-d$ be considered a circuit?

Answer (score 3):

I dare to state that there is no non-simple cycle of length $5$ in any graph. If there is such a cycle then it must contain a simple cycle of length not less than $3$. The remaining two (or less) edges cannot form a cycle.